# hunspell suggest hyphen for words misspelled without hyphens

Tags: hunspell

I have the words `wi-fi`, `spell-check`, `line-break` in my `.dic` file.
I want the following suggestions:

`wifi` -> Suggest `wi-fi`
`spellcheck` -> Suggest `spell-check`
`linebreak` -> Suggest `line-break`

What aff setup do I need to allow that?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. With hunspell 1.7.0, an empty `.aff` file, and a `.dic` file with hyphenated words, I get correct suggestions, e.g.,  `linebreak` suggests `line-break` and also a misspelling like `linbreak` suggests `line-break`. I tested this on the command line using `hunspell -d mydictionary`. Could you explain a bit more about your setup/use case/environment in which you use hunspell?

Comment: Ok, I checked it with hunspell 1.7.0 as well and it works. 
My bad, I am using a library called [Typo.js](https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js) where this does not work. I assumed that this is a direct port of hunspell, but I guess that it's not and the issue is within the library itself.
I originally thought that you need a special `.aff` file to make this work and that it would not work out of the box.

Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Typo.js the alphabet of characters that can be used in suggestions is limited to a-z. See [line 788 of the source code](https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js/blob/14f97490f59cd19b9838c8e8dee5170971fc5995/typo/typo.js#L788):

```js
self.alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Interestingly, below this line there is a commented out piece of code that determines the alphabet from the dictionary itself, which would have prevented the issue in the question. However, without using that code you can add characters manually in this list. Replace that line in the source by the following:

```js
self.alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-";
```

Then the suggestions will include dictionary items with a hyphen. Code (adapted from https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js/blob/master/examples/node/index.js):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="typo.js"></script>
<script>
function checkwords(){
    var is_spelled_correctly = dictionary.check("normal");
    console.log( "Is 'normal' spelled correctly? " + is_spelled_correctly );
    var is_spelled_correctly = dictionary.check("line-break");
    console.log( "Is 'line-break' spelled correctly? " + is_spelled_correctly );
    var is_spelled_correctly = dictionary.check("linebreak");
    console.log( "Is 'linebreak' spelled correctly? " + is_spelled_correctly );
    var array_of_suggestions = dictionary.suggest("linebreak");
    console.log( "Spelling suggestions for 'linebreak': " + array_of_suggestions.join( ', ' ) );
}
    var dictionary = new Typo("yourdictionary", false, false, { dictionaryPath: ".", asyncLoad: 1, loadedCallback: checkwords });
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
Typo.js test<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Dictionary used for testing:

```
5
normal
word
wi-fi
spell-check
line-break
```

Output:

```
Is 'normal' spelled correctly? true
Is 'line-break' spelled correctly? true
Is 'linebreak' spelled correctly? false
Spelling suggestions for 'linebreak': line-break
```